# @Json in JBehave's Story

Tags: automated-tests, bdd, jbehave, serenity-bdd, scenarios

Parametrised Scenarios can be achieved by different ways (http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html) in JBehave's story file. But I want to know whether Json can be used in parametrised scenarios like the following example:

**Given** ........................
**When** ....@Json{user}
**Then**  .........................

**Examples:**
@Json: user{ 
        fName: "xxxxx" 
        lName: "yyy" 
}

*Thanks in advance..*

Answer (score 0):

The provided example will not work.

Possible options are the following ones.

> **Inlined parameters:**

```
Given ..............
When .... {
   "fName": "xxxxx",
   "lName": "yyy"
}
Then  ..............
```

> **ExamplesTable:**

```
Given ...............
When .... <userJson>
Then  ..............

Examples:
|userJson                            |
|{ "fName": "xxxxx", "lName": "yyy" }|
```